# I am trying to install a new light in an existing three wire ceiling box with an already installed switch, but can't get it to work right

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling, light

This is a new home, several ceilings have light junction boxes already installed with the wall switches already installed as well. I have a ceiling light I want to install but I must not be installing the wiring correctly. My first attempt and when I turned the power back on the light worked but I could not turn the light off. Other attempts and the light has never worked since. (The bulbs are not burned out.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the wires in the ceiling and a picture of the wires going to the switch?

Comment: I already replaced all the coverings. I have nine foot ceilings. I should have snapped some pictures but I do not have any. May have to be I need to..

Comment: The problem is we're just guessing without pictures and more details. The problem could be in the ceiling fixture, could be in the switch, could be some of each.

Comment: While we're making assumptions, in what part of the world is this home located?  Is it new to you or new construction?  Electrical codes vary over both space and time.

Comment: Would if he safe to assume that you don't remember how the wiring was originally connected (since presumably it once worked)?

Comment: Hello, I had to go out of town. I live in northern Virginia. I do have pictures now. I have taken a picture of the switch box. The left switch is for the hallway lights. The right switch is for the light. I also took a picture of the lighting instructions. Hopefully now I can find a way to attach the pictures.

Comment: Hello, hopefully I have added enough pictures to allow you to determine what I need to do. Thanks in any event.

Comment: As to the comment the wiring once worked, this is a new home. I think the lights worked once because I wired them wrong. The lights came on when I turned the breaker back on but the light switch did not turn the lights on or off. Somehow I wired everything hot. @brhans

Answer (score 2):

In the ceiling:

- Bundle of whites - all neutral, presumably one in, one to switch box, one out to next fixture/receptacle/etc.
- Bundle of blacks - all hot, presumably one in, one to switch box, one out to next fixture/receptacle/etc.
- Bundle of bare wires - all ground - always together, doesn't matter where they go.
- One red wire - switched hot from switch

In the switch box, you likely have multiple cables because of multiple switches. You need to make sure the black, red and white (if relevant) going to the switch are all from the same cable.

- White - neutral - probably capped in back. *Might* be connected with other white wires to feed other locations, though that can get a bit tricky. You only need to worry about the neutral if you want to install a smart (motion/timer/WiFi/etc.) switch, and you don't even consider doing that until you have a standard toggle switch working first.
- Black - hot - connect to one of the switch *screws*. It looks like black (and red) is connected to a "backstab" connection. If it is connected to a "backstab" connection, move it to a screw.
- Red - switched hot - connect to the other switch screw. Same note regarding "backstab" connections.
- Ground - correctly connected to screw.

To connect the fixture:

- Connect fixture hot wire (smooth wire according to the directions, on other fixtures it may be black or red or blue) to the *red* switched hot wire with a wire nut.
- Connect fixture neutral wire (ribbed wire according to the directions, on other fixtures it may be white) to the *white* neutral wires with a wire nut. You may need to replace the existing wire nut.
- Connect fixture ground wire (should be green or bare) to the other bare ground wires with a wire nut. You may need to replace the existing wire nut.